# Attributes / vars in tooltipster are ignored

Tags: javascript, variables, attributes, tooltipster

I've been trying for two days to figure out why tooltipster (which is great btw) is not taking into account any var declared in the javascript / head section. For instance:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
        var data = 'toto';
        contentAsHTML: true,
        animation: 'slide',
        delay: 100,
        content : $(data)
        });
});
</script>
```

with:

```
<img src="Pics/winter.png" alt="winter" border="1" class="tooltip" />
```

is not working at all (meaning the tooltip is not showing up in the HTML page). I tried several coding variations, including adding ' ; ' etc. but it doesn't change the result.
I also tried to get an element's attribute using:

```
content : '$(this).attr('alt')'
```

which is my final goal, and it doesn't work either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a quick [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0uytnj9/) to demo the "correct" way of setting the content of the tooltip from the originating element - on it's intialization.

The reason this wasn't working before was due to:

1. You declaring the variable `data` within the JSON object passed to the `tooltipster` function - this is invalid syntax for JavaScript.
2. Your second attempt was closer, but using `this` in the `content` property is an ambiguous reference to an "outside" `this` scope - likely unrelated to the tooltipster instance or HTML node you were after.

Here's the amended code that should do what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
        contentAsHTML: true,
        animation: 'slide',
        delay: 100,
        functionInit: function(instance, helper) {
          var alt = $(helper.origin).attr('alt');
          instance.content(alt);
        }
    });
});
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The most probable reason is

```
var data = 'toto';
```

`contentAsHTML`,`animation`,`delay`,`content` etc are options that [**tooltipster**](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) accepts.

But when it is coming across `var data = 'toto';` it will through an error since it is not an option which `tooltipster`can accept

Comment: Thank you for this fast and neat reply. However, how do you retrieve the attribute of a given image such as 'alt' and pass them to the content section? Other topics and Google search indicate me that var is someone comonly accepted ?! I am quite puzzled/ For instance:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897699/tooltipster-displays-image-as-tooltip-on-second-time-hover